# Create a sheet in Excel work book

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to access excel which is located in my local. Below is my coding.

```
public class readexcel {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File readexcelfile = new File("S:\\Testing\\user.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(readexcelfile);
        XSSFWorkbook wrbk = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet firstsheet0 = wrbk.getSheetAt(0);
        String data0 = firstsheet0.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println(data0);
```

Whenever I run the above code, I'm getting the below error message.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet
>   index (0) is out of range (0..-1)     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.validateSheetIndex(XSSFWorkbook.java:1043)
>     at
>   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.getSheetAt(XSSFWorkbook.java:834)
>     at TestNG.readexcel.main(readexcel.java:17)

Comment: You're creating a new workbook. That doesn't have any sheets in it. Note that you're not actually loading the existing file... you're opening a stream to it, and then ignoring it.

Comment: If I remember right, you can create the new workbook with the underlying stream in the constructor, such as `XSSFWorkbook wrbk = new XSSFWorkbook( fis );`

Comment: thanks..... working

Answer (score 0):

@Orin2005 comment is correct. 
Before addressing a sheet, you need to create it. 
One way to do it is:

```
XSSFWorkbook wrbk = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```